# MariaDB - Data at rest encryption in 10.4.14 Windows 2019

Tags: database, encryption, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I'm at a loss, and with an extremely tight timeline, I'm rapidly running out of options.  Posting here is my last-ditch attempt to get this working.  I am trying to get my test environment of MariaDB 10.4.14 completely encrypted for data at rest (including logs, tmp files, etc).  I have followed all the instructions, including the fact that the keyhole has to be in ANSI, but I am still getting the same error message:

```
[ERROR] mysqld.exe: file-key-management-filename is not set
[ERROR] Plugin 'file_key_management' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'file_key_management' registration as a ENCRYPTION failed.
```

Here's what I have in the my.cnf file:

```
plugin-load-add = file_key_management
loose_file_key_management_file = C:/Program Files (x86)/MariaDB 10.1/data/keyfile.txt
```

The key file is unencrypted at the moment; I'll eventually encrypt it once I have this figured out.

I have gone into the database and have confirmed that the file_key_management plugin is listed in the ALL_PLUGINS table, but is showing as "DISABLED".  When I try and manually change that to "ACTIVE", I get an error that "root@localhost does not have permissions" (I'm wondering if this is the root of my problem but don't know how to correct it).

Any ideas or thoughts are appreciated.  I have been spending days reading everything I can find and I have to get this working by Tuesday, and am getting extraordinarily frustrated.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Update: I've now tried in my plugin and file key management statements underscores and dashes, C:\ and C:/ format, double quotes, single quotes, and anything else i can think of but without luck.

Comment: The documentation is flaky for Windows. You have to restart the service to get changes recognized. For me all forward-slashes work, and I tested it was working with an obviously bogus path to start.

Answer (score 0):

So after much frustration and swearing, I seem to have it working now...this is what I've added to my.cnf

```
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
loose_file_key_management_filename = C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB\data\keyfile.txt
```

I'm sure I tried this the other day so not sure why it's working now, but doesn't matter to me - it works :o)
Chris